# Can you take back a draw offer?

Tags: draw

Is it possible to take back the draw offer if the opponent was not immediately replying to it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. Rule 9.1.2.1 of [the FIDE rules](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=208&view=article) says it all:

> **9.1.2.1** A player wishing to offer a draw shall do so after having made a move on the chessboard and before pressing his clock. An offer
>   at any other time during play is still valid but Article 11.5 must be
>   considered. No conditions can be attached to the offer. In both cases
>   the offer **cannot be withdrawn** and remains valid until the opponent
>   accepts it, rejects it orally, rejects it by touching a piece with the
>   intention of moving or capturing it, or the game is concluded in some
>   other way.

(rule 11.5 is about not distracting the opponent during his move)

It's expected that the opponent takes his time to think about the offer, just as he probably spends time on thinking about his next move. He isn't required to actually refuse the offer, just making a move is quite normal too (once he touches a piece to move the offer is over, see above).

Comment: Also: *"9.1.2.2  The offer of a draw shall be noted by each player on his scoresheet with the symbol (=)."* so this makes it official, so to speak.

Comment: @gented Just to be extra clear: writing it down is not a condition for a valid offer. Especially when considering the situation that you may be (a little) behind with your notation the alternative would be very confusing.